# Why same images have different brightness in QtWidgets app and standard Preview app?

Tags: c++, qt

I wrote some code that show two widgets:

```
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QLabel>
#include <QtGui/QPixmap>

#include <QtWidgets/QWidget>
#include <QtGui/QPalette>
#include <QtGui/QPixmap>
#include <QtGui/QBrush>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QPixmap pix;
    pix.load(":/mira.jpg");

    QLabel lbl;
    lbl.resize(pix.size());
    lbl.setPixmap(pix);
    lbl.show();

    QWidget wgt;
    QPixmap pix2;
    pix2.load(":/mira.jpg");
    QPalette pal;
    pal.setBrush(wgt.backgroundRole(), pix);
    wgt.setPalette(pal);
    wgt.setAutoFillBackground(true);
    wgt.resize(pix2.size());
    wgt.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

But I noticed that brightness of the image displayed by this widgets and brightness of the same image displayed by standard macOs Preview.app is slightly differ:

Different brightness evidence

[image]

It's not an illusion, I checked it with macOS tool DigitalColorimetor.app and brightness is realy differ, thats true!

Why same images have different brightness in QtWidgets app and standard Preview app? Which image representation is true?

UPD: image opened in (left to right) Preview.app, Qt Creator (Resource View), Google Chrome

Qt does something wrong

[image]

Comment: How would we know what transformation(s) this "macOs Preview.app" may be applying? I think that's a question for Apple.

Comment: @JesperJuhl, Is there really no standard with one color scheme of a monitor that would allow representing images on a monitor in the same way?

Comment: regardless of monitor calibration information (if an application even reads/respects it, which many don't and whether it is actually correct/accurate - which it often isn't), we have *no way* to know if that app changes the image before it displays it. Outside of highly regulated fields like diagnostic quality medical monitors (which other cost $15000 or more), it's basically the wild west as far as the hardware goes. And as for applications - meh.

Comment: @JesperJuhl, I think that no image transformations are performed. After all, the Preview application was created for editing and viewing photographs and should display them in the most plausible way. Perhaps this Qt is doing wrong with photos?

Comment: I hope that anyone who understands this will be interested in and check that the decoding of jpg images by the Qt library is correct. By the way, Google Chrome displays photos with the same brightness as Preview, and it does not matter which application is in the input focus.

Comment: Note that as far as I'm aware `Qt` doesn't decode jpegs itself.  Rather it makes use of libraries such as libjpeg.  It might be instructive to see whether or not the same brightness discrepancies exist with other formats such as, e.g., png, gif etc.